# Python import single resource from module as resource.module

Tags: python, import

I want to import only `torch.device` from Pytorch, but not import the whole module because of its size. 
 I can't use `from torch import device` because the name 'device' collides with names in my programme. 
 The following also doesn't work:

```py
>>> from torch import device as torch.device
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Of course, I can use
`from torch import device as torch_device`. 
But isn't there a nicer way to import `torch.device` and reference it in my programme as `torch.device`?

Comment: Correct me if im wrong, but even `from torch import device as foo` would import the whole module `torch`, it would just not put it into your namespace. So you would not save anything anyway.

Comment: Is it? I'm sorry then this question makes no sense.